# How to authenticate against an azure blob storage for reading/writing blobs from within an azure pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-identity, azure-python-sdk

I have an azure pipeline which runs some python tests in which I use an instance of DefaultAzureCredential (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-identity/azure.identity.defaultazurecredential?view=azure-python) from azure.identity python package. Tests run fine locally with the help of a security group defined in portal azure which I am a member of which gives access to those blob storages. As I inspect how DefaultAzurecredential works on my local PC by looking up the value of _successful_credential attriubte, it turns out that it succeeds authenticating using azure.identity._credentials.azure_cli.AzureCliCredential. Now I need those tests to run on azure devops as well, but not sure how to get this authentication done there. I have spent hours reading documentations on microsoft website and github pages for azure sdk for python without luck. Any help would be highly appreciated. I have a rough understanding that this should be possible using kind of a azure service connection but I could not find anything relevant on the web.

Answer (score 0):

As it is written [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.identity.defaultazurecredential?view=azure-dotnet):

> Provides a default TokenCredential authentication flow for applications that will be deployed to Azure. The following credential types if enabled will be tried, in order:
>
> - EnvironmentCredential
> - WorkloadIdentityCredential
> - ManagedIdentityCredential
> - SharedTokenCacheCredential
> - VisualStudioCredential
> - VisualStudioCodeCredential
> - AzureCliCredential
> - AzurePowerShellCredential
> - AzureDeveloperCliCredential
> - InteractiveBrowserCredential

For your purpose ['EnvironmentCredential'](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.identity.environmentcredential?view=azure-dotnet) seems to be great fit. As you need to setup few Environment variables:

[image]

Please also make sure that use here Service Principal have proper permissions to access Storage Account.

If you use self-hosted agent you can consider using 'ManagedIdentityCredential'

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Though I am still missing the part around how to connect my pipeline to such a service principal. To be specific, what type of service connection do I need to create, and how to attach it to my pipeline. Would appreciate links to some pages that describe how to do so, if you know of any.

Comment: Service connection can be useful when you have sober built-in tasks. Here since you have just coffee which needs authentication for Default azure credential you just need arrive mentioned environment variables. The DAC class detects it and authenticate using Azure_client_id etc